# Text analysis using stat_text raising error : IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, indexoutofboundsexception

I am running some text analysis on text scraped from the web using a package called text_stat. In multiple cases I got this error

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Code:

```
# Importing packages
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bfs
from textstat.textstat import textstat

# Declaring URL
wikipedia_privacy_url = requests.get("https://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Privacy_policy")

# Parsing webpage content using Beautiful Soup
wikipedia_privacy_soup = bfs(wikipedia_privacy_url.content, "html.parser")

# Extracting the desired xPath
wikipedia_privacy_text = wikipedia_privacy_soup.find_all("div", {"class": "mw-body"})

# Declare an empty string to concatenate the multiple extracted strings
wikipedia_privacy = ''

# Extracting text
for text in wikipedia_privacy_text:

# Concatenating all the extracted text into one variable
    wikipedia_privacy = wikipedia_privacy + text.text
```

After that, I try to use a method from the text_stat package to analyze the extracted text.

```
textstat.smog_index(wikipedia_privacy)
```

which should return a float, but instead I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amin/Desktop/scrapy_project/text_stat.py", line 46, in text_pro
    SMOG_Index = textstat.smog_index(text)
  File "/home/amin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/textstat/textstat.py", line 96, in smog_index
    poly_syllab = self.polysyllabcount(text)
  File "/home/amin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/textstat/textstat.py", line 89, in polysyllabcount
wrds = self.syllable_count(word)
  File "/home/amin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/textstat/textstat.py", line 29, in syllable_count
    if text[0] in vowels:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

textstat.smog_index(text) code:

```
def smog_index(self, text):
            if self.sentence_count(text) >= 3:
                    poly_syllab = self.polysyllabcount(text)
                    # SMOG = 3.129 + round(poly_syllab**.5)
                    SMOG = (1.043 * (30*(poly_syllab/self.sentence_count(text)))**.5) + 3.1291
                    return round(SMOG, 1)
```

Comment: It seems that the `text` you pass in is an empty string. The error occurs at the line `SMOG_Index = textstat.smog_index(text)`. It would help if you posted it.

Comment: @Pushkin wikipedia_privacy has the text stored in it, I just double checked.

Comment: @Pushkin textstat.smog_index(textt) is a function of the textstat package

Comment: @Pushkin from textstat                                                                                               def smog_index(self, text):
                if self.sentence_count(text) >= 3:
                        poly_syllab = self.polysyllabcount(text)
                        # SMOG = 3.129 + round(poly_syllab**.5)
                        SMOG = (1.043 * (30*(poly_syllab/self.sentence_count(text)))**.5) + 3.1291
                        return round(SMOG, 1)

Comment: What happens in `some_index` if i`self.sentence_count(text) < 3` ? There is nothing returned.

Comment: none, since you don't have enough sentences to be analyzed.

Comment: Isn't that a problem?  You have a method that either returns something or doesn't return at all.

Comment: It returns, it just implicitly returns a `None` value.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the syllable_count doesn't do a good enough job checking to see if text is blank. As such when it attempts to slice the text it generates an error. I added a couple simple lines to check if the string is valid.

Fix:

```
def syllable_count(self, text):
            count = 0
            vowels = 'aeiouy'
            text = text.lower().strip(".:;?!)(")
            if text == None and text != "":
                    if text[0] in vowels:
                            count += 1
                    for index in range(1, len(text)):
                            if text[index] in vowels and text[index-1] not in vowels:
                                    count += 1
                    if text.endswith('e'):
                            count -= 1
                    if text.endswith('le'):
                            count += 1
                    if count == 0:
                            count += 1
                    count = count - (0.1*count)
            return (round(count))
```